# Determining which direction phone is rotating with just accelerometer

Tags: android, android-sensors

So, right now I'm grabbing the accelerometer data and converting them to a decently rough estimate of the angle at which the phone is being held. For right now I'm just focused on the yaw axis.

My area of interest is between 0 and 45 degrees on the yaw axis, so I made a limited queue of the past 5 to 10 readings and compared the numbers to determine if it's going up or down, which kind of works, but it is slow and not really as precise or reliable as I'd want it to be.

Is there a way you can kind of just determine which direction your phone is rotating with just the accelerometer and the magnetic field sensor I guess, without keeping a history of past readings, or something like that? I'm really new to sensor manipulation and Android in general. Any help understanding would be great.

Comment: No, not with a single measurement in time.

Comment: As @ChrisStratton said, you have to take more than 1 measurement of time, and compare a previous measurement to a current one in order to determine the delta theta.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're looking for here, position or velocity. Generally speaking, you don't want to get a position measurement by using integration on the accelerometer data. There's a lot of error associated with that calculation.

If you literally want the "direction your phone is rotating," rather than angular position, you can actually get that directly from the gyroscope sensor, which provides rotational velocities. That would let you get the direction it's rotating from the velocity without storing data. You should be aware that not every phone has a gyroscope sensor, but it does seem like the newer ones do.

If you want the absolute orientation of the phone (position), you can use the Rotation Vector sensor. This is a combined sensor that automatically integrates data from several of the sensors in one go, and provides additional accuracy. From this, you can get roll-pitch-yaw with a single measurement.  Basically, you first want to get your data from the [Rotation_vector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) sensor. Then you use the sensor data with [getRotationMatrixFromVector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrixFromVector%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29).  You can use the output from that in getOrientation (see the same page as the previous link), which will spit out roll-pitch-yaw measurements for you.  You might need to rotate the axes around a bit to get the angles measured positive in the direction you want.